# Make <object> tag fill the whole window and resize with it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I have a NaCl plugin for Chrome that I'd like to fill the whole window with.
HTML is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="container,box">
      <object class="internal,box"></object>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried a couple of styles:

1. ```
       html {
         height: 100%;
       }
       .box {
         position:absolute;
         left/right/top/bottom: 0;
         display:block;
         padding: 5px
       }
   ```

   fills the whole window,  remains with the default size, 300x150.
2. ```
       html, body, .box { padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100% }
       .container { padding: 5px; }
   ```

   fills the whole window but it width/height is unaffected by padding so it overflows the containing

Did anyone face similar problem? Any CSS solutions?
I need it to work only in Chrome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
.internal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```